# How to use custom button for Google Friend Connect API login button?

Tags: google-friend-connect

I am using Google Friend Connect API to login to my site. And using the default function google.friendconnect.renderSignInButton(params) to render the sign in button. Can I use my own custom button to log into my site or can I customize the button to sync in with the website design. Because the customization option provided in http://code.google.com/apis/friendconnect/docs/gfc_buttons.html are not helpful as I need a completely different looking button than these.

Comment: just found out, google is retiring GFC on March 1, 2012 ... :( ... again have to use something else to login to my website ...

Comment: Yeah, question's essentially irrelevant because GFC is now gone. You should probably be using OpenID and/or OAuth 2.

Answer (score -1):

I have a post on my blog which will help you create or have the GFC widget back on your blog or website. the post is on [How to add Google friend connect on blogger](http://www.fantasysurf.blogspot.com/2014/05/how-to-add-google-friend-connect-to.html) , in this tutorial are the two ways on which you can add the GFC widget.

Comment: Link only answers are frowned upon, can you post the relevant extract here?